# How to store value in a variable and use that variable to filter data in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have to take input which i store in  a variable and use that value to filter out data like this

```
u = 'Jun'
duration = compda.query("Month==u").groupby('name').duration.mean().reset_index().values.tolist()
```

this doesnt work, however

```
duration = compda.query("Month=='Jun'").groupby('name').duration.mean().reset_index().values.tolist()
```

works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, you can use @ to pass variables ([documentation here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)):

```
u = 'Jun'
duration = compda.query('Month == @u').groupby('name').duration.mean().reset_index().values.tolist()
```